# The first element of a matrix power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, time-series, block-matrices

Let $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ be the following block matrix:

$$A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
a^T & \alpha\\
I_{n-1} & 0_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a, 0_{n-1} \in \Bbb R^{n-1}$ are vectors and $\alpha$ is a scalar. Then, is there a closed form for

$$e_1^T A^k e_1,\quad k\in\Bbb N$$

i.e., the top left element of $A^k$?

By closed form, I mean something like the combination of sums ($\sum$) or products ($\prod$) or anything else that would make solving for $k$ the equation 
$$e_1^T A^k e_1= 1/2$$
easier. Such a $k$ is called the half life of an AR(p) process whose coefficients are the first row of $A$.

Explanation for the [time-series](/questions/tagged/time-series) tag: This problem arises from computing the impulse response function, and therefore the half life, of a general AR process.

Edit: $A$ is diagonalisable, non singular, and has spectral radius < 1 for what it's worth. So one numerical way to solve the equation $e_1^T A^k e_1= 1/2$ I can think about is to first diagonalise it as $A=QDQ^{-1}$, then we can define for any *real number* $k$ the matrix power $A^k$ as
$$A^k=QD^kQ^{-1}$$
And once we obtain $Q$, $D$ numerically, we can expect to get a polynomial in $\lambda_{1,\cdots, n}^k$ where $\lambda$ are eigenvalues of $A$, and thus is solvable by software.

Comment: Is $a$ a matrix ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, it's a (n-1) vector.

Comment: It's much easier to compute $A^k$ if we have
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\a^T & \alpha}
$$
for what that's worth

Comment: Yes that would be triangular. But i dont think it's possible to have such a nice form for the AR(p) structure (tried and failed).

Comment: If this can help, with $n=4,k=6$, $3\alpha a_0^2+2\alpha a_1+a_0^6+6a_0^2a_1^2+6a_0a_1a_2+a_1^3+5a_1a_0^4+a_2^2+4a_2a_0^3$. Nothing appetizing.

Comment: What AR process do you have? It might be easier to work with it than with block matrices.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo one whose lag 1 to lag p coefficients coincide with the first row of $A$ i.e. $[a^T, \alpha]$.

Comment: Isn't $A$ a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo up to some row/column exchanges, yeah. But that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to implement a solution in software, you can do the following. You want $e_1^TA^ke_1$, which is the first entry of $A^ke_1$. If you write 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} a_1&a_2&\cdots&a_n&\alpha \\
1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
0&0&\cdots&1&0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
 then
$$
Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 
\sum_{j=1}^na_jx_j+\alpha x_{n+1}\\
x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So if we write $z_k$ for the first entry of $A^ke_1$ (and $z_j=0$ when $j<0$) we have the recursion
$$
z_{m}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}z_{m-j}+\alpha z_{m-n-1}.
$$
This recursion is very easy to implement in software. One could also attempt to solve the recursion explicitly, by looking at the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence#Characterization_in_terms_of_exponential_polynomials) (of the recursion).

Comment: Thanks! Actually my main challenge isn't how to compute this value, but rather how to solve the equation $|e_1^T A^k e_1|=1/2$ for *k*. One nasty thing is that $k$ is *continuous* here ($k\in\Bbb R_+$), which is why I mentioned diagonalising $A$ first to make the potentially fractional power $A^k$ well defined.

Comment: The "real power" thing will only work naturally if the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive. Do you have any condition that guarantees that? From the couple of simple examples I tried, non-positive and non-real eigenvalues pop up easily.